# OpenSSH for Windows denies public key login with AD user

Tags: windows, windows-10, ssh, openssh, sftp

On a`Windows 10, v 1903` system, I am running `v 8.0.0.0` of OpenSSH for Windows and trying to connect to it, using public key, from a remote location

Username and password authentication works fine. `SecureFX SFTP` client reports `AUTH_SUCCESS` with Public Key, but the connection closes immediately with a `TCP` error.

Checking the logs of `SSH` server, it says there is a fatal error with forking an unprivileged child, immediately after it fails to find the login user, possibly in the Active directory.

```
14036 2019-09-26 13:06:28.265 debug1: trying public key file C:\\Users\\abc\\.ssh/authorized_keys
14036 2019-09-26 13:06:28.265 debug1: C:\\Users\\abc\\.ssh/authorized_keys:5: matching key found: RSA SHA256:ajHmaaQPXU3VIPnMFJcz8ce2pwHZodRfudLtdLLmgJg
14036 2019-09-26 13:06:28.265 debug1: C:\\Users\\abc\\.ssh/authorized_keys:5: key options: agent-forwarding port-forwarding pty user-rc x11-forwarding
14036 2019-09-26 13:06:28.265 Accepted key RSA SHA256:ajHmaaQPXU3VIPnMFJcz8ce2pwHZodRfudLtdLLmgJg found at C:\\Users\\abc\\.ssh/authorized_keys:5
14036 2019-09-26 13:06:28.265 debug3: mm_answer_keyallowed: publickey authentication: RSA key is allowed
14036 2019-09-26 13:06:28.265 debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 23
14036 2019-09-26 13:06:28.265 debug3: mm_sshkey_verify entering [preauth]
14036 2019-09-26 13:06:28.265 debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 24 [preauth]
14036 2019-09-26 13:06:28.265 debug3: mm_sshkey_verify: waiting for MONITOR_ANS_KEYVERIFY [preauth]
14036 2019-09-26 13:06:28.265 debug3: mm_request_receive_expect entering: type 25 [preauth]
14036 2019-09-26 13:06:28.265 debug3: mm_request_receive entering [preauth]
14036 2019-09-26 13:06:28.265 debug3: mm_request_receive entering
14036 2019-09-26 13:06:28.265 debug3: monitor_read: checking request 24
14036 2019-09-26 13:06:28.265 debug3: mm_answer_keyverify: publickey 00000252D826D600 signature verified
14036 2019-09-26 13:06:28.265 debug1: auth_activate_options: setting new authentication options
14036 2019-09-26 13:06:28.265 debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 25
14036 2019-09-26 13:06:28.265 Accepted publickey for abc from 127.0.0.1 port 62042 ssh2: RSA SHA256:ajHmaaQPXU3VIPnMFJcz8ce2pwHZodRfudLtdLLmgJg
14036 2019-09-26 13:06:28.265 debug1: monitor_child_preauth: abc has been authenticated by privileged process
14036 2019-09-26 13:06:28.265 debug3: mm_get_keystate: Waiting for new keys
14036 2019-09-26 13:06:28.265 debug3: mm_request_receive_expect entering: type 26
14036 2019-09-26 13:06:28.265 debug3: mm_request_receive entering
14036 2019-09-26 13:06:28.280 debug3: mm_get_keystate: GOT new keys
14036 2019-09-26 13:06:28.280 debug1: auth_activate_options: setting new authentication options [preauth]
14036 2019-09-26 13:06:28.280 debug2: userauth_pubkey: authenticated 1 pkalg ssh-rsa [preauth]
14036 2019-09-26 13:06:28.280 debug3: user_specific_delay: user specific delay 0.000ms [preauth]
14036 2019-09-26 13:06:28.280 debug3: ensure_minimum_time_since: elapsed 0.000ms, delaying 8.339ms (requested 8.339ms) [preauth]
14036 2019-09-26 13:06:28.280 debug3: send packet: type 52 [preauth]
14036 2019-09-26 13:06:28.280 debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 26 [preauth]
14036 2019-09-26 13:06:28.280 debug3: mm_send_keystate: Finished sending state [preauth]
14036 2019-09-26 13:06:28.280 debug1: monitor_read_log: child log fd closed
14036 2019-09-26 13:06:28.280 error: lookup_principal_name: User principal name lookup failed for user 'abc\\def' (explicit: 1355, implicit: 1355)
14036 2019-09-26 13:06:28.280 debug1: generate_s4u_user_token: LsaLogonUser() failed. User 'abc\\def' Status: 0xC0000062 SubStatus 0.
14036 2019-09-26 13:06:28.280 debug3: get_user_token - unable to generate token for user abc\\def
14036 2019-09-26 13:06:28.280 error: lookup_principal_name: User principal name lookup failed for user 'abc\\def' (explicit: 1355, implicit: 1355)
14036 2019-09-26 13:06:28.280 debug1: generate_s4u_user_token: LsaLogonUser() failed. User 'abc\\def' Status: 0xC0000062 SubStatus 0.
14036 2019-09-26 13:06:28.280 error: get_user_token - unable to generate token on 2nd attempt for user abc\\def
14036 2019-09-26 13:06:28.280 error: unable to get security token for user abc\\def
14036 2019-09-26 13:06:28.280 fatal: fork of unprivileged child failed
14036 2019-09-26 13:06:28.280 debug1: do_cleanup
```

I checked their `GitHub` page for similar issues - [this](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues/1213) - looked like a similar problem, but stated as fixed in `OpenSSH` latest version. I got the latest version and installed it, but the same issue persists.

Is this a different issue, or maybe something I need to enable on my side...?

Comment: Yes, password authentication works fine.